# After installing ssl certificate images won't show

Tags: images, ssl

This is my website https://thequintessentialmind.com/

After installing ssl certificate images won't show or show as missing.

I have updated almost all the urls to https but the problem insists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have Adaptive Images plugin installed?

The [author suggests](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/switched-to-https-does-not-work-anymore/#post-9281419) for now:

> Can you check if the urls in your admin Settings > General page do
>   contain the “https” instead of “http”? They should contain the “https”
>   and (sorry about this inconvenience) you need to update your Adaptive
>   Images settings one more time after this.
>
> Also, for a proper and complete migration from HTTP to HTTPS, I would
>   advice performing a url rewrite in your database, which will replace
>   each and every url of your domain from “http” to “https”.

But this is a fresh problem so there's a possibility that this solution will not work 100%, so I recommend to watch that thread. You can also disable this plugin until this problem is fixed by the author and maybe that will solve your problem for now.

Comment: Thank you! How did you find out which plugin was causing the issue?

Comment: I googled the error message _Original image not found or not available._. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the fact that the images were uploaded in a non-ssl environment. Thus, in the database, that is the reference. If you look at the URL in the media library, you will see that they are a http:// and not https://

There is a plugin that fixes the problem, Really Simple SSL by Rogier Lankhorst
Delete the image files and re-upload with a slightly different image name.

I have done both methods, depending on the development state of the site.

Comment: I tried to delete and re-upload the image but still, the image won't show.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it in the [`wp-config.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) helped me, so now I can see images after changing to https.

Comment: yes, but I want a floating plugin that you don't have to modify the core WP files